# Question words and Adverbs

Tags: adverbs

Are the question words, such as when, where, who, why and how, adverbs? If yes, can anyone explain why they are adverbs?

Comment: "Who" is a pronoun and (in traditional grammar) the others are adverbs. They qualify as adverbs because they typically function as heads of adjuncts questioning time, location, reason, and manner/means. Note, though, that "how" can also be an adjective in, for example, "How was the concert?"

Comment: Incidentally, you asked an identical question on ELU.

Comment: Note that 'they typically function as heads of adjuncts questioning time, location, reason, and manner/mean' (to quote BillJ) has to be included as a sufficient reason in the definition of _adverb_ alongside the more prototypical 'they modify verbs', if they are to be lumped alongside say 'quietly' and 'well'.